# Dot matrix printer: Orientation changes to portrait for odd pages

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Printer prints every odd page in portrait orientation.

```
private void Form1_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("Custom", 700, 325);
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize);
    //printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
}

 private void DrawGridBody(Graphics g, int y_value)
 {
        int x_value;

        for (int i = 0; (i < NUM_ROWS_PER_PAGE) && ((i+m_printedRows) < ((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Rows.Count); ++i)
        {
            DataRow dr = ((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Rows[i + m_printedRows];
            x_value = 0;

            string text = dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(0).ToString();
            g.DrawString(text+"**", this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)x_value, (float)y_value + 10f);
            y_value += ROW_HEIGHT;

            g.DrawString("page " + Convert.ToString(m_printedRows), new Font("Lucidia Console", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 60, 10);

            g.DrawString("1 " + dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(0).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(370, 20));
            g.DrawString("2 " + dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(0).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(390, 46));
            g.DrawString("3 " + dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(0).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(30, 40));
            g.DrawString(dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(1).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(70, 180));
            g.DrawString(dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(2).ToString() + " " + dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(3).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(70, 202));
            g.DrawString(dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(4).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(70, 224));
            g.DrawString(dr.ItemArray.ElementAt(5).ToString(), new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, 285));
            g.DrawString("***********", new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, 300));
            g.DrawString("***********", new Font("Lucidia Console", 10), Brushes.Black, new Point(550, 315));
        }

        m_printedRows += NUM_ROWS_PER_PAGE;
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
    }

    private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowPosition = SPACE_ABOVE_HEADER;

        rowPosition += ROW_HEIGHT;

        // draw each row
        DrawGridBody(e.Graphics, rowPosition);

        // see if there are more pages to print
        if (MoreRowToPrint())
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        else
            m_printedRows = 0;
    }

    private bool MoreRowToPrint()
    {
        return ((DataTable)dataGridView.DataSource).Rows.Count > m_printedRows;
    }
```

Comment: `DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true` is called inside `DrawGridBody` method, which is not necessary. Remove it and try again to check if it is causing the orientation problem.

Comment: thanks for the response, removing pageorientation from DrawBody and
putting
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

in Form Load did the trick

It is working with XPS and Canon LBP2900

What changes do i need to print on continue paper on dot matrix printer
           DataTable dt
            dt.Columns.Add("Branch");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("AcType")
            dt.Columns.Add("Curency")
            dt.Columns.Add("ActNum")
            dt.Columns.Add("ChqNo")

Comment: hard to read the comment, too many words. Edit the question, append your update at the end.

Comment: sorry, i m new here
it is working so far with XPS and canon laser
I v to check it in dot matrix printer to print in continuous paper

Comment: what is the problem when printing on continuous paper with dot matrix printer? does it still have the orientation issue?

Comment: Or you could check if [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29709/Line-Printer-Class-in-C) helps you, it is a wrapper class for printing on line printer.

Comment: it is working so far need to try some more with item positioning!!!! I had to find a way to print in device fonts

Comment: it is ok but slower to print!!! need to this for check printing, insert check number in datagrid print it and then insert into sql server!!!!